# Calculate Batch Pairwise Sinkhorn Distance in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I have two tensors and both are of same shape. I want to calculate pairwise sinkhorn distance using [`GeomLoss`](https://www.kernel-operations.io/geomloss/).

**What i have tried:**

```
import torch
import geomloss  # pip install git+https://github.com/jeanfeydy/geomloss

a = torch.rand((8,4))
b = torch.rand((8,4))

geomloss.SamplesLoss('sinkhorn')(a,b)
# ^ input shape [batch, feature_dim]
# will return a scalar value

geomloss.SamplesLoss('sinkhorn')(a.unsqueeze(1),b.unsqueeze(1))  
# ^ input shape [batch, n_points, feature_dim]
# will return a tensor of size [batch] of distances between a[i] and b[i] for each i
```

However I would like to compute pairwise distance where the resultant tensor should be of size `[batch, batch]`. To achieve this, I tried the following to use broadcasting:

```
geomloss.SamplesLoss('sinkhorn')(a.unsqueeze(0), b.unsqueeze(1))
```

But I got this error message:

> ValueError: Samples `x` and `y` should have the same batchsize.

Comment: So you would like to have a 2D tensor of distances between `a[i]` and `b[j]` at each batch index pairs `(i, j)`, right?

Comment: @Ivan Yes, Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the documentation doesn't give examples on how to use the distance's forward function. Here's a way to do it, which will require you to call the distance function *`batch`* times.

We will construct the distance matrix line by line. Line `i` corresponds to the distances `a[i]<->b[0]`, `a[i]<->b[1]`, through to `a[i]<->b[batch]`. To do so we need to construct, for each line `i`, a `(8x4)` repeated version of tensor `a[i]`.

This will do:

```
a_i = torch.stack(8*[a[i]], dim=0)
```

Then we calculate the distance between `a[i]` and each batch in `b`:

```
dist(a_i.unsqueeze(1), b.unsqueeze(1))
```

Having a total of *`batch`* lines we can construct our final tensor `stack`.

---

Here's the complete code:

```
batch = a.shape[0]
dist = geomloss.SamplesLoss('sinkhorn')
distances = [dist(torch.stack(batch*[a[i]]).unsqueeze(1), b.unsqueeze(1)) for i in range(batch)]
D = torch.stack(distances)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.
I was also considering loop-based solution as an option. Appreciate your help!.